# Spring CORS Filter problem in light of Spring Cloud microservices with Zuul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

**Given**: angular frontend application sends requests to backend microservice through gateway microservice. The backend is in Spring Cloud.

**Question:** how to correctly configure CORS filters to get rid of the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://gateway-service:5555/api/useful-service/myentities/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:4200', but only one is allowed.
```

That's what I have written so far:

### Gateway Service

My main class in the gateway serivice has 3 annotations: @SpringBootApplication, @EnableZuulProxy and @Configuration. So as I don't confgigured any security thing I presume that the Spring Security is not being used therefore I need to configure Spring MVC's CorsFilter. I do that like this *(comments are for future searchers)*:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
    //corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
    corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("*"); //wildcard that will simply copy the value of the request's Origin header
    // into the value of the Response's Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, effectively allowing all origins.
    // You can add specific origins instead if you wish to limit them.
    corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    configSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
    return new CorsFilter(configSource);
}
```

### Useful Service

The main class over here is annotated with @EnableResourceServer and @SpringBootApplication. According to my "business rules" I would like to have Spring authorization (url security, and in the future the method security also) so as I configured Spring Security in general and OAuth2 and in partucular I should configure security's cors filter as well. Here's relevant security snippet that enables cors:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(); // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
    }
}
```

And that's how I configure the cors functionality of spring security:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Unfortunatelly I got the error mentioned above, if you have an idea how to fix it please tale.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this problem was fixed with a DedupeResponseHeader-filter.
See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/pull/866

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)